# Prove the linear transformations T and S are equal

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T: \mathbb{R}^n\mapsto{}\mathbb{R}^m$ and $S: \mathbb{R}^n\mapsto{}\mathbb{R}^m$ be linear transformations, and let $b_1,...,b_p$ be vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $T(b_1)=S(b_1), T(b_2)=S(b_2), ..., T(b_p)=S(b_p)$. Prove that $T(v)=S(v)$ for all $v\in{}Span\{b_1,...,b_p\}$

I'm not sure what there is to prove here, probably just because I don't understand it... But doesn't the fact that $T(b_1)=S(b_1), T(b_2)=S(b_2), ..., T(b_p)=S(b_p)$ prove that $T(v)=S(v)$ for all $v\in{}Span\{b_1,...,b_p\}$?

Comment: Yes, it does.  Why would you be asked to prove this statement, if it didn't?

Comment: No. Elements in span$\{b_1,...,b_p\}$ are of the form $\sum_{i=1}^p \alpha_i b_i$ for some $\alpha_i \in \Bbb R$.

Comment: As long as you're given that a linear transformation is defined as $T(ax + by) = aT(x) + bT(y)$ (or some equivalent definition), I agree, there's not much to prove here. How I would formally write it is take, WLOG, a vector in the span, apply $T$ to it and apply $S$ to a copy of it, and show that they're equal. Here, your vector might be $C_1 b_1 + C_2 b_2 + \cdots + C_p b_p$.

Comment: Yes, this is obvious but the question asks for a formal proof of the statement. By definition of linear span, any element $v\in\textrm{span}\{b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_p\}$ must be of the form $v=\sum\limits_{i=1}^p\alpha_i b_i$ where the $\alpha_i$'s are scalars. Now, we have,

$$T(v)=T(\sum\limits_{i=1}^p\alpha_i b_i)=\sum_{i=1}^p\alpha_iT(b_i)=\sum_{i=1}^p\alpha_iS(b_i)=S(\sum\limits_{i=1}^p\alpha_i b_i)=S(v)$$

Answer (score 1):

Well, the fact that $T(b_1)=S(b_1), T(b_2)=S(b_2), \ldots , T(b_p)=S(b_p)$ holds doesn't literally prove that $T(v) = S(v)$ holds for all $v\in\text{Span}\{b_1,\ldots,b_p\}$, but the proof is indeed very short.